# Ruby on Rails: Rest API to submit a list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, list, rest

I am confused about RoR's handling of REST lists.

The Rails 3 routes magic creates (among others)

```
POST /items create one item
GET  /items list all items
```

Now, I want to have exactly this PLUS
the possibility to POST a **list** of items (in XML).

What's the best way to do it?

Semantically, `POST /items` to me sounds about creating a list, not a single item
Can I 'overload' this in the controller?
Or do I need to create a new routing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code your controller to either accept a single item or an array of them. This isn't in any way reflected in the routes, but only concerns your controller, as POST-parameters are not specified in the routes.

It is accepted (and generally assumed) behavior to accept a single item there. But you are free to accept whatever you like.